# Render a variable in React html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```
const getTime = () => {
    const today = new Date();
    const time = today + ' ' + today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
    return {time};
}

export default function UpdateButton() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const today = new Date();
    const time = today + ' ' + today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
    return (
        <div>
            <Button variant="contained" className={classes.button}>
                Update
            </Button>
            <text>Last Updated: {getTime}</text>
        </div>
    )
};
```

I am trying to render the time in the text tag but it keep throwing error. How do I resolve this issue. This is under react framework.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Can you share us the error message too ?

Comment: Try `getTime()` instead of `getTime`. It’s a function, not a value, and `return time` instead of `return {time}` unless you’re trying to return an object with a time property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getTime` function should return a string and not an object, and you should call it in the JSX - `getTime()`:

```js
const getTime = () => {
  const today = new Date();
  const time = today + ' ' + today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
  return time;
}

function UpdateButton() {
  return (
    <div>
      <button variant="contained">
        Update
      </button>
      <text>Last Updated: {getTime()}</text>
    </div>
  )
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <UpdateButton /> ,
  root
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

SInce you didn't share the error I'm going to guess it's because you return a function in your JSX:

```
const getTime = () => {
    const today = new Date();
    const time = today + ' ' + today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
    return time;
}

export default function UpdateButton() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const today = new Date();
    const time = today + ' ' + today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
    return (
        <div>
            <Button variant="contained" className={classes.button}>
                Update
            </Button>
            <text>Last Updated: {getTime()}</text>
        </div>
    )
};
```